# Azure Key Vault who did what auditing

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-log-analytics

I have setup log analytics for Azure Key vault and can find the user IPs through this query.

```
AzureDiagnostics
| summarize count() by CallerIPAddress
```

But how can I find the activities done by a user(with a username), including the secrets/keys viewed?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the correct Operation Name and get the results

```
search * 
| where Category=="AuditEvent"  and OperationName == "SecretGet"
| order by TimeGenerated desc
```

Comment: It should be there

Comment: may I know the field name?

Comment: seems you cannot, it has only IP address, instead try using Powershell

Comment: how to do using powershell?

Comment: check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59525218/how-to-audit-secret-key-access-in-key-vault

Comment: There is an 'idenitity' field which has the user email id, and in log analytics query, we cannot get it. IS that the difference?